# In Laravel 9, how can I make Vite work properly?

Tags: laravel, vite, laravel-9

I'm trying to work Laravel 9 on my remote server, not my local machine, and not using Docker. The server environment already has its domain and set SSL. So I installed Laravel 9 and Breeze with React.  Then when I run `npm run dev,` nothing shows up on the page, and I get these errors on the browser console.

```
GET https://[::]:5173/@vite/client net::ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID
GET https://[::]:5173/resources/js/app.jsx net::ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID
GET https://[::]:5173/@react-refresh net::ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID
```

I searched many solutions on Google and almost tried all I found, but nothing worked.

These are what I tried.

1. I added `ASSET_URL` on my .env file, but it didn't work.
2. I tried putting these on `vite.config.js,` but it also didn't work.

```
 server: {
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        hmr: {
            host: 'localhost'
        }
    },
```

Even replacing `0.0.0.0` with the server IP didn't work either.

3. I Tried running the command `npm run dev -- --host APPURL,` didn't work.
   (* APPURL means my URL, which connected to the Laravel project, not the string itself)

What should I do from here? Is there any solution to this? I almost feel like I can't use Laravel anymore. Or is there any way to use React with Laravel 9 without Vite? I couldn't find anything about this.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I found out this problem was not because any of Laravel but was just setting of the remote server. I redo everything I did on a fresh server, and the problem has gone.

Answer (score 0):

i have exact same problem, vite is listening on my external ip but the application tries to load assets rom "https://[::]:5173/" for some reason

edit: you can change the ip by setting this in the vite.config.js

```
...

export default defineConfig({
   ...
   server: { hmr: { host: 'your server ip (ip only)' } }
});
```